# Lighting a candle for a dead person

Tags: tradition

In Islam is there a tradition to light a candle for a person who died, or maybe while having zihara (presnce at certain time in the tomb of a person and praing there)?

Comment: Lighting a candle does not have any Islamic significance, although some Muslims may have adopted the culture to do so.

Answer (score 1):

No such thing in the Qur'an and sunnah to my knowledge, so avoid it